Unable to update test cases using TTM4J API
I am using the Tricentis Test Management Tool on Jira - TTM4J for keeping a track of requirements, test cases and test runs. I wish to automate some practices now, and therefore resort to their API.
I am trying to update test cases on TTMJ Test cases on Jira using TTM4J API, however I keep getting an internal server error and no changes are made on Jira.
postman screenshot
How does one go about updating test cases using the TTM4J API?
Here's how I have hit the api endpoint
URL
{{baseUri}}/v1/projects/{{projectKey}}/test-cases/{{testCaseKey}}

baseUri = "https://api.ttm4j.tricentis.com/"
projectKey = my project key
testCaseKey = a valid test case key

Headers
included Bearer tokens in Authorization
Body
{
    "fields": {
        "summary": "example",
        "description": "example",
        "priority": "High"
    },
    "ttmFields": {
        "precondition": "example",
        "steps": [
            {
                "expectedResult": "example",
                "description": "example"
            }
        ]
    }
}

Obtained Response
status code : 500
body :

{
"message": "Unable to update fields in Jira for {tesCaseKey}"
}

Postman logs
PUT /v1/projects/<censored>/test-cases/<censored> HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: <censored>
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.42.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: <censored>
Host: api.ttm4j.tricentis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 405
 
{
"fields": {
"summary": "example",
"description": "example,
"priority": "High"
},
"ttmFields": {
"precondition": "example",
"steps": [
{
"expectedResult": "example",
"description": "example"
}
]
}
}
 
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: <censored>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-amzn-RequestId: <censored>
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length: 60
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
RequestId: ZkWl9TVa
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
x-amzn-Remapped-Connection: keep-alive
x-amz-apigw-id: <censored>
Cache-Control: no-store
x-amzn-Remapped-Server: <censored>
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Version: <censored>
x-amzn-Remapped-Date: <censored>
Content-Length: 60
Age: 2
Connection: keep-alive
Via: <censored>
 
{"message":"Unable to update fields in Jira for <censored>. "}

 Was Expecting
updated test case with response body as given in the documentation
example
{
  "id": "a00fbc94-8e87-44da-b89e-85b83d9c1c65",
  "key": "TE-1",
  "project": "TE",
  "testType": "Manual",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "Test 1 status",
    "description": "Test 1 description",
    "status": "Backlog",
    "priority": "High",
    "labels": [
      "My Label"
    ]
  },
  "ttmFields": {
    "precondition": "A precondition",
    "steps": [
      {
        "testCaseKey": "TE-2",
        "testCaseId": "10000"
      }
    ]
  }
}

